# How do I get shutdown codes using terminal in macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, shutdown

How can I use Terminal to get my shutdown codes, going back to the weekend?

I'm on Mojave 10.14.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just enter the following command into Terminal:

```
log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Previous shutdown cause"' --last 168h
```

The 168h refers to 168 hours, which I've used so that the command goes back a week (since you want to capture the weekend).

However, you can change the `168` to another value if you like.